# is it posible to merge feature to release with git flow

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm using gitflow and Sourcetree.

By default, Sourcetree make me merge Feature to Develop, Develop to Release, and Release to Prod

Thing is sometimes, one merge Feature to Develop, and it fails, so it needs more work.

Then, If someone, want to make a release, git flow will merge those errors to Release.

I would prefer to merge the only Feature that has been validated to release.

Is it posible to do that with git flow?

Comment: Is the "git flow" you're referring to a product or a piece of software? I generally see that being used to refer to a workflow/process, which is something you can one-off change or modify to do whatever you want.

Comment: https://github.com/nvie/gitflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

GitFlow is a set of open source scripts which you can modify according to your needs.

but in this case it has nothing to do with gitflow, its a pure coding. You can commit bad content regardless if you are using git flow or not and you should not do it unless you have checked your code before committing it so git flow is not the case here.

#### How can you tell if the commit is good or bad?

Once you have answer to this question you can simply modify the feature script which responsible for merging feature into develop and block the merge.

> I would prefer to merge the only Feature that has been validated to release.

As noted in the previous paragraph once you know how to identify good commit simply modify the gitflow script according to your needs.

---

#### Sources

Check this around line 313
https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/blob/develop/git-flow-feature

```
# lines 313 >
# merge into BASE
git_do checkout "$DEVELOP_BRANCH"
if [ "$(git rev-list -n2 "$DEVELOP_BRANCH..$BRANCH" | wc -l)" -eq 1 ]; then
    git_do merge --ff "$BRANCH"
else
    if noflag squash; then
        git_do merge --no-ff "$BRANCH"
    else
        git_do merge --squash "$BRANCH"
        git_do commit
        git_do merge "$BRANCH"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: So, I need to edit gitflow script... is there any other way? As I use Sourcetree, I'm afraid it get complicated, thinking about update that could reset all changes, etc...

Comment: In my opinion it has nothing to do with gitflow since developers should not commit bad code to any dev branch, but since you asked how to do it using git flow the answer is that you will need to update the scripts.

Comment: well, it is not about bad code, code could easily work in feature, but have a integration problem in dev. those situations happens a lot

Comment: yes, but understanding your answer, the answer might be no, because, I should modify several scripts Feature > Rel, Feat > Prod, so git flow seems a bit useless, or unadapted to my needs

Comment: You simply need to block the merge into develop, once you stop it there it will not be merged into prod since it will not be in develop

Comment: I assume you will if it will not be done with gitflow

Answer (score 0):

If a merge to develop leads to problems, you should not commit it. My recommendation would be to merge the develop branch into the feature branch before you merge the feature into develop and resolve any conflicts there (be it merge conflicts or logical conflicts).

Also - if you do work with the gitflow model - you shouldn't merge anything into release (except maybe bugfixes). Instead, release should be a new branch from the current state of develop and if you think that there are any features that are not ready for shipping yet you can turn them off in the release branch.